# Issue using withConverter into a WriteBatch in Flutter (Error Type)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

I've started to use Firestore withConverter to convert my data in local objects.
But when I'm using it in a batch to set a new document, it gives me a strange error.

Here is what I called orderRef.

[orderRef definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0VfJ.png)

Here is where I try to use it in a batch

[using it in a batch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqSSO.png)

I get the error _TypeError (type '(OrderData, SetOptions?) => Map<String, Object?>' is not a subtype of type '(Object, SetOptions?) => Map<String, Object?>').

If I replace orderDoc (= orderRef.doc(orderId)) by FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('order).doc(orderId), it's working.

Can you please help me on that ? I would like to get rid of collection names in my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*FYI: Next time, please include your code samples in code blocks, and not as images. Code blocks don't get deleted from free image services, and allow for easy copy-pasting, etc.*

---

The reason why you're getting that error is because you're missing some typing.

Instead of this:

```dart
final orderRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('order')
  .withConverter<OrderData>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => OrderData.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
    toFirestore: (order, _) => order.toJson(),
  );
```

Do this:

```dart
final DocumentReference<OrderData> orderRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('order')
  .withConverter<OrderData>(
    fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => OrderData.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
    toFirestore: (order, _) => order.toJson(),
  )
  .doc(); // You need this before you can set the data for a new doc.
```

Then, when you you're using the `batch`, you need to type your request as well:

```dart
batch.set<OrderData>(orderRef, orderData);
```

---

As a side note, it's better to transfer the `snapshot` directly to the model, in the converter, and do the data access within the model. This becomes more apparent when you need to access other properties, like `snapshot.id`, for example.